# How to Configuring App for Multi-Window Mode?

Tags: android, android-studio, multi-window, android-7.0-nougat

In android Multi-Window Support , how to configure app for multi-window mode?

Which attribute need to set in  manifest's **activity** or **application** node to **enable** or **disable** multi-window display?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The minimum requirement to enable multi-window for a specific activity (or the entire application) is to add the `resizeableActivity=true` parameter to the `<activity>` (or `<application>`) tag.

Here is an overview of the [Android Developers' Multi-Window Support](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/multi-window.html) guide:

---

If your app targets **Android N**, you can configure how and whether your app's activities support multi-window display. You can set attributes in your manifest to control both size and layout. A root activity's attribute settings apply to all activities within its task stack. For example, if the root activity has `android:resizeableActivity` set to true, then all activities in the task stack are resizeable.

> **Note**: If you build a multi-orientation app with a version of the SDK lower than Android N, and the user uses the app in multi-window mode, the system forcibly resizes the app. The system presents a dialog box warning the user that the app may behave unexpectedly. The system does not resize fixed-orientation apps; if the user attempts to open a fixed-orientation app under multi-window mode, the app takes over the whole screen.

- **android:resizeableActivity**

Set this attribute in your manifest's **activity** or **application** node to enable or disable multi-window display:

```
android:resizeableActivity=["true" | "false"]
```

If this attribute is set to **true**, the activity can be launched in **split-screen and freeform modes**. If the attribute is set to **false**, the activity does **not support multi-window mode**. If this value is false, and the user attempts to launch the activity in multi-window mode, the activity takes over the full screen.

If your app targets **Android N**, but you do not specify a value for this attribute, the attribute's value **defaults** to **true**.

- **android:supportsPictureInPicture**

Set this attribute in your manifest's **activity** node to indicate whether the activity supports **picture-in-picture** display. This attribute is ignored if `android:resizeableActivity` is **false**.

```
android:supportsPictureInPicture=["true" | "false"]
```

**Layout attributes**

With **Android N**, the **layout** manifest element supports several attributes that affect how an activity behaves in multi-window mode:

- `android:defaultWidth`

  Default **width** of the activity when launched in freeform mode.
- `android:defaultHeight`

  Default **height** of the activity when launched in freeform mode.
- `android:gravity`

  Initial placement of the activity when launched in freeform mode. See the **Gravity** reference for suitable values.
- `android:minHeight, android:minWidth`

  Minimum height and minimum width for the activity in both split-screen and freeform modes. If the user moves the divider in split-screen mode to make an activity smaller than the specified minimum, the system crops the activity to the size the user requests.

**For example,** the following code shows how to specify an activity's default size and location, and its minimum size, when the activity is displayed in freeform mode:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity">
<layout android:defaultHeight="500dp"
      android:defaultWidth="600dp"
      android:gravity="top|end"
      android:minHeight="450dp"
      android:minWidth="300dp" />
```

Comment: resizableActivity from manfiest related things working  in Preview Version   ?
as i tried to create on simple app and got some issue 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205216